# Ошибка при запуске тестов Django

Tags: python, django, юнит-тесты, django-rest-framework, импорт

у меня есть директория tests, в которой лежат мои тесты, при запуске команды python3 manage.py test, которая схватывает все тесты в проекте, у меня выдает такого типа ошибку на каждую директорию моего проекта:

### ERROR: overschool.users (unittest.loader._FailedTest.overschool.users)

ImportError: Failed to import test module: overschool.users
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 440, in _find_test_path
package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 350, in _get_module_from_name
**import**(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'overschool.users'

и подобное падает на все мои приложения проекта